# why it show 404 error in laravel login page in ubuntu cloud server?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

i have installed fresh laravel and laravel auth/ui on my server and configure the vhost and .htaccess file , it display welcome page but when i click on login or register link in welcome page it show 404 error below are the .htaccess and vhost code.

```
.htaccess code     
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase //
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

and here is the 000-default.conf code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject/public
ServerName example.test
<Directory "/var/www/html/public">
    allow from all
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::view('about', 'about')->name('about');

    Route::get('users', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');

    Route::get('profile', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'show'])->name('profile.show');
    Route::put('profile', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
});

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Auth::routes();
```

Comment: What about your routes?

Comment: question updated , but it work on local machine not on server

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter where it runs. To visit ```/login``` page, you need a login route. As far as I remember, ````Auth::routes()```` should be providing them. Check that function details. If anything wrong, you can recreate those routes on web.php file. Please remove the duplicated method. I don't think it causes any issue but it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your apache2 configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject/public
ServerName example.test
<Directory /var/www/html/myproject/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```